# C#: Inaccesible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with this code:

```
private void altaCliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FILElocalidades localidad = new FILElocalidades();
    cbLocalidad.DataSource = localidad.traerLocalidad();
    cbLocalidad.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
}
```

> Error  2   'GestionReclamos.FILElocalidades.traerLocalidad()' is inaccessible due to its protection level  C:\Users\Matias\Desktop\Incidencias1\PL\altaCliente.cs  43  48  PL

When I have this:

```
public class FILElocalidades
{
    public IList<Localidades> traerLocalidad()
    {
        IList<Localidades> lista = new List<Localidades>();         
        DataAcessLayer datos = new DataAcessLayer();
        try
        {
            datos.setConsulta("SELECT NOMBRE FROM CIUDADES");
            datos.openConexion();
            datos.ejecutarConsulta();
            while(datos.lector.Read())
            {
                Localidades localidad = new Localidades();
                localidad.Nombre = datos.lector.GetString(0);
                lista.Add(localidad);
            }

            return lista;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {

            datos.cerrarConexion();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the definition for Localidades class

Comment: Try FILElocalidades localidad = new Full.Namespace.Path.FILElocalidades(); and let's see.

Comment: Most likely `FILElocalidades.traerLocalidad()` is declared as a private method.